# 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' in Python

Tags: python, data-science, data-analysis

function anagrams(s1, s2) is a Boolean valued function, which returns true just in case the string s1 contains the same letters as string s2 but in a different order. The function should be case insensitive --- in other words it should return the same value if any letters in either s1 or s2 are changed from upper to lower case or from lower to upper case. You may assume that the input strings contain only letters.
[image]

The function find_all_anagrams(string) takes a string as input and returns a list of all words in the file english_words.txt that are anagrams of the input string.
the function should return a list [word1, ..., wordN] such that each word in this list is a word in the dictionary file such that the value function anagrams(string, word) are True

```
def anagrams( string1, string2 ):
    str_1 = string1.lower()
    str_2 = string2.lower()
    if str_1 == str_2:
        return False
    else:
        list_1 = list( str_1 )
        list_1.sort()
        list_2 = list( str_2 )
        list_2.sort()
        return list_1 == list_2

def find_all_anagrams( string ):
    with open("english_words.txt") as f:
        word_list = []
        for line in f.readlines():
            word_list.append(line.strip())
        list1 = [i.split() for i in word_list]
    for j in list1:
        if anagrams( string, j ) == True:
            return list1
        else:
            return []
```

ERROR kept saying this: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

for example,word_list contains:
['pyruvates', 'python', 'pythoness', 'pythonesses', 'pythonic', 'pythons', 'pyuria', 'pyurias', 'pyx', 'pyxes']

Expected output below
[image]
Part of the txt file shown on the right:
[image]

Update:
I think I just solved it,here are my codes:

```
def find_all_anagrams( string ):
    list1 = []
    with open("english_words.txt") as f:
        word_list = []
        for line in f.readlines():
            word_list.append(line.strip())
    for i in word_list:
            if anagrams( string, i ):
                list1.append(i)
    return list1
```

Comment: i.split() creates a list, hence the elements of list1 are list, what exactly are you trying to achieve with i.split()?

Comment: In the code you've displayed you only call the `.lower()` function on `str_1` and `str_2`. What *are* `string1` and `string2`?

Comment: how are you calling the function?

Comment: For `word_list` to look like this, there must be a single word on each line. Are you sure that is case? if that is the case, why did you call `split` on every element of `word_list`?

Comment: I've no idea..... maybe my logic is wrong, the output is so wired...

Comment: @Cecilia in that case skip the `list1 = [i.split() for i in word_list]` part and use `word_list` directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function at this part:

```
list1 = [i.split() for i in word_list]
```

Let's see what the documentation tells us about that function:

> ## str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
>
> **Return a list** of the words in the
>   string, using sep as the delimiter string. If maxsplit is given, at
>   most maxsplit splits are done (thus, the list will have at most
>   maxsplit+1 elements). If maxsplit is not specified or -1, then there
>   is no limit on the number of splits (all possible splits are made).

It returns a list, and you added that list to your own list. I can see that `word_list` is meant to hold lines of words. Let's assume that `word_list` looks like this:

```
word_list = ["hello darkness my", "old friend I've", "come to see you", "again"]
```

What happens after `list1 = [i.split() for i in word_list]`?

```
list1 = [i.split() for i in word_list]
print(list1)
```

Output:

```
[['hello', 'darkness', 'my'], ['old', 'friend', "I've"], ['come', 'to', 'see', 'you'], ['again']]
```

As you can see, elements are individual lists. At this part of your code:

```
for j in list1:
    if anagrams( string, j ) == True:
        return list1
    else:
        return []
```

`j` is a list, therefore here:

```
def anagrams( string1, string2 ):
    str_1 = string1.lower()
    str_2 = string2.lower()
```

`str_2 = string2.lower()` is trying to call [lower](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) method on a list, which isn't a valid method for a `list` object, and that's why Python is complaining.

List Comprehension might look "cool" but often using simple loops benefits your code's readability, and in some cases might even avoid mistakes like this one. Here is my alternative:

```
list1 = []
for i in word_list:
  for word in i.split():
    list1.append(word)
```

see the output:

```
print(list1)
```

> ```
> ['hello', 'darkness', 'my', 'old', 'friend', "I've", 'come', 'to', 'see', 'you', 'again']
> ```

Single words as you intended.

Comment: @Cecilia Int that case the resulting list is `[['pyruvates'], ['python'], ['pythoness'], ['pythonesses'], ['pythonic'], ['pythons'], ['pyuria'], ['pyurias'], ['pyx'], ['pyxes']]`. Elements are still individual lists and each has a single element of its own

Comment: Thanks, but the output is not what I expected.
[]
[]
[]

Comment: @Cecilia Output of my code? How did you use it? What was your expected output?

Comment: I added a picture above(expected output), not your codes, it's mine output, three empty [ ]

Comment: @Cecilia can you add the whole program? At least enough of the code that I can run it on my own and see what's going on. You are not even calling those functions in the question.  And also please add `english_words.txt`

Comment: I just added part of the txt,and more details about the first function,I'm pretty sure the first function is right,just don't know what's the mistake of the second function.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the error message, list does not have an attribute `.lower` 
I guess what you meant do to is access a string within the list with a `.lower`  attribute. 
For example:

```
mylist[index].lower()
```

where index corresponds to the string position within the list.